# Troubles with subqueries using union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using union so I can "merge" the data from 3 separate queries.
My table has many columns but I have to use only title and ID.

My data:

```
ID Title 
1 'trainings'  
2 'trainings'
3 'workshops'
4 'workshops'
5 'workshops'
6 'qwerty'
7 'qwerty2'
8 'qwerty3'
```

What I want to do is show only the titles of Trainings, workshop and combine these other three's as "Others" and then count each one of them .
Example:

```
Count Title
2     trainings
3     workshops
3     others
```

What I have tried:

```
select  Title, count(*) as Count From Events where Title like '%Training%' 
group by Title 
union 
select Title, count(*) as Count From Events where Title like '%Workshop%' 
group by Title
union 
select 'Others' as Title,count(*) as Count from Events e where e.Title not like '%workshop%' and e.Title not like '%training%'
Group by Title
```

But I don't get the desired result, indeed I take 1 as per "Other's" column:

```
Count Title
1     Others
2     Trainings
3     Workshops
```

But if I run only this code:

```
select 'Others' as Title,count(*) as Count from Events e where e.Title not like '%workshop%' and e.Title not like '%training%'
Group by Title
```

it will work all fine, the "error" is only when I combine with the two others.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Learn the very significant difference between UNION and UNION ALL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a single query with aggregation?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count],
       CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Training%' THEN 'Trainings' 
            WHEN Title LIKE '%Workshop%' THEN 'Workshops'
            ELSE 'Other'
       END AS Title
FROM dbo.Events
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Training%' THEN 'Trainings' 
              WHEN Title LIKE '%Workshop%' THEN 'Workshops'
              ELSE 'Other'
         END;
```

If you prefer not to repeat the `CASE` expression, you can use a CTE:

```
WITH Titles AS(
    SELECT CASE WHEN Title LIKE '%Training%' THEN 'Trainings' 
                WHEN Title LIKE '%Workshop%' THEN 'Workshops'
                ELSE 'Other'
           END AS Title
    FROM dbo.Events)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count],
       Title
FROM Titles
GROUP BY Title;
```

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot. But, what if I want to do with my exact query ? Isn't there any way to sort this out just by that way?

Comment: What do you mean *"what if I want to do with my exact query"*? Your exact query doesn't work, as you said. And why would you want to scan your table 3 times, when you can do it once? You wouldn't read a book 3 times, to find all instances of 3 different words, you'd read it once and note the locations of any of the 3 as you go. The same applies here.

Comment: What I meant is that I wanted to do it with Union clause and see what my misconception was. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression for aggregation:

```
select (case when title in ('Trainings', 'Workshops') then title
             else 'Others'
        end) as title,
       count(*)
from events e
group by (case when title in ('Trainings', 'Workshops') then title
               else 'Others'
          end);
```

If you don't want to repeat the `case` expression you can use a lateral join with `apply`:

```
select v.title, count(*)
from events e cross join
     (values (case when title in ('Trainings', 'Workshops')
                   then title else 'Others'
              end)
     ) v(title)
group by v.title;
```

EDIT:

If you need the `LIKE` you would just extend this (there are no examples in the question where this is necessary):

```
select v.title, count(*)
from events e cross join
     (values (case when title like '%trainings%' then 'Training'
                   when title like '%workshops%' then 'Workshop'
                   else 'Others'
              end)
     ) v(title)
group by v.title;
```

Comment: Okay but still not the wanted result. It counts all the rows I have inside, and it doesn't really check if there are '%training%' or '%workshop%'

Comment: @Leo . . . You would use the same idea, but tweak the logic in the `case` expression.  There are no examples in your sample data where `like` is needed, so that seems superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Count, Title
FROM (SELECT ID, CASE WHEN Title IN ('trainings', 'workshops') THEN Title ELSE 'others' END Title
FROM Events) AS T
GROUP BY Title

Comment: Please add more detail in answer than just a code.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way

```
select * from (
select  count(case when Title like '%trainings%' then 1 end) as trainings,
  count(case when Title like '%workshops%' then 1 end) as workshops,
  count(case when Title not like '%workshops%' and Title not like '%trainings%' then 1 end) as Other from Events
  )tab
  UNPIVOT 
( 
Counts FOR Title IN (trainings, workshops,Other)
) 
AS UnpivotTable order by Counts
```